# Prove the energy is constant in a PDE?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[image]

I calculated the

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dE(t)}{2\,dt} & = \int_\Omega u_tu_{tt}+DuDu_t+u^3u_t\,dx \\
& =\int_\Omega [u_t(u_{tt}-\Delta u)+u^3u_t] \, dx+\int_{\partial \Omega} u_t \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} \, ds = \int_{\partial \Omega} u_t \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} \, ds
\end{align}
$$

However, I don't know how to prove $$\int_{\partial \Omega} u_t \frac{\partial u}{\partial v}ds$$ is zero by the conditions given in the problem?

Can anyone help me about this? Thanks so much!

Can anyone help me explain why $u_t\cong 0$ on $\partial \Omega$?
Thanks so much!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $u_t\cong 0$ on $\partial \Omega$!

Comment: Thanks! But can you explain for me why that is $0$? I cannot see that from the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: $u(x,t) = 0$ in $\partial \Omega \times [0,T]$ so..

Comment: It might help you to look at it this way: fix a $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ and consider the function $g(t) = u(x_0,t)$.  What is the value of $g$ for all $t$?  What is the derivative of such a function?  Was anything special about $x_0$? :)